# Salesfor Quote object Created By and Subtotal field accessibility

Tags: quote

For the Salesforce Quote object, is it possible to change the Created By and Subtotal fields to read/write or is it a hard limitation that these fields are read-only?

Answer (score 2):

**SubTotal**
The field is read-only as documented [at here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_quote.htm).

[image]

**CreatedBy**
You can allow some users to set audit fields (Created* and LastModified*) fields while creating records. See [this help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000334139&type=1) on how to enable it.